# How to convert String with comma to Integer and Double

Tags: java, parsing

I am new to Java programming. I am trying to read excel file where the cell data is in String value. I would like to get the value in double or int. Here's the example data: **3,199,800.00** and  **400,573.80**. Now, I want to get the value as **3199800** and **400573.8**.

I can get those values using this code:

```
String value = valueCell.getStringCellValue()
    .trim()
    .replace(",", "")
    .replace(".00", "")
    .replace(".10", ".1")
    .replace(".20", ".2")
    .replace(".30", ".3")
    .replace(".40", ".4")
    .replace(".50", ".5")
    .replace(".60", ".6")
    .replace(".70", ".7")
    .replace(".80", ".8")
    .replace(".90", ".9");
```

Is there a way where I can minimize the above code. Thank you!

Edited: Just to add, I want to keep the result as a string. thank you!

Comment: Is this POI? You could try calling getNumericCellValue() right away.

Answer (score 4):

Well you have to remove the commas in your case so the easiest way I could thing of is this one

```
String someExcelNumber = "3,199,800.00";
System.out.print(Double.parseDouble(someExcelNumber.replace(",","")));
```

First you remove the commas then you parse them to double or any other format up to you, but if the commas wasn't removed a NumberFormatException will be thrown

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to trim off excess zeros, you can simply parse them straight into numbers with `Double.parseDouble` or `Integer.parseInt` (after stripping the commas). So for example:

```
Double.parseDouble(number.replace(",", ""))
```

If you wanted to keep it as a string, you could use the following regex:

```
number.replace(",", "").replaceFirst("(\\d+)\\.0+$|(\\d+\\.[1-9]+)0*$", "$1$2")
```

Which replaces any zeroes that a preceded by a `.` and any number of digits.

Comment: There are comma's in the number. so, `Integer.parseInt()` will give the `NumberFormatException`

Comment: I was referring to the OPs current approach, in the question the commas are already being stripped from the string.

Comment: I tried this solution:
number.replace(",", "").replace("(?<=.\\d)0+$", "")

but I'm getting the same value.

Comment: Sorry I meant `replaceAll` not `replace`. Feel free to try my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Possible using only parseDouble:

```
static String st1 = "3,199,800.00";
static String st2 = "400,573.80";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(st2.replaceAll(",", "")));

    System.out.println((int)Double.parseDouble(st1.replaceAll(",", "")));

}
```

results:

400573.8

3199800

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static String convert(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll(",|\\.00$|(?<=\\..)0$", "");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(convert("3,199,800.00"));
    System.out.println(convert("400,573.80"));
}
```

output:

```
3199800
400573.8
```

Comment: Hello, this is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Is there any website where i can learn what you did? thanks in advance. So I could understand what you did.

Comment: This doesn't work for an input like `400,573.860`.

Comment: @HenryTwist I don't know the correct output for that input.

Comment: @JCALTSako I learned a lot from this site.

Comment: You're right @saka1029, I just assumed the OP wanted to strip the trailing zeroes.